# How to calculate the energy and power of the force of lift that acts on a cruising plane?

Tags: energy, gravity, power, lift

Say we have a plane flying at constant speed and altitude. Looking at the y axis, the lift cancels out the force of gravity as it maintains constant height. I want to calculate the energy used to generate this lift as well as the power needed to generate this lift. I find it difficult as there is no movement involved to calculate energy as Force * displacement.

My reasoning is this. Since the system on the y axis is in balance we should have

Lift = mg

If this lift would be the only force acting on the plane of mass m for a time t then the displacement would be Lift/m * t^2/2 = gt^2/2. Therefore the energy used to generate this force over a time t is the force times the displacement or E = mg * gt^2/2 = mg^2t^2/2

Given this power should be the work done (energy) over a period of time divided by that time E/t = mg^2t/2

My concern is that power should really be constant, not time dependent and therefore I suspect there is a mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: Time is inherent in the definition of power: "power is the amount of energy transferred or converted per unit time."

Comment: I guess what I meant was power should not be proportional to time. A plane engine does not get more and more powerful the longer it flies. Also, choosing different values for the time I evaluate the energy over yield different values for power which again does not make sense.

Comment: It can have used more and more energy the longer it flies - this can translate as constant power. The issue seems to be about the difference between power and energy, which is time.

Comment: That is what I am thinking intuitively. Power should be constant while energy consumed should grow linearly with time?

Comment: Yes, in an "ideal aircraft". Naturally real-life is more eventful, involving fuel-expensive take-offs, air of different qualities at different times and altitudes etc..

Comment: There are whole classes and books dedicated to the performance of aircraft, and this sort of analysis is covered early on usually. Draw a free body diagram and [understand the relationship between lift and drag](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Aerospace_Engineering/Aerodynamics_and_Aircraft_Performance_(Marchman)/01%3A_Introduction_to_Aerodynamics) to proceed.

Comment: This [NASA](https://practicalaero.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/NASA-SP-367.pdf) reference is great intro into aerodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

If the aircraft is *not* actually moving up or down, then there is zero vertical displacement, and so the energy imparted by the lift force is zero.  (And so is the power.)  This is a standard result that commonly trips up intro physics students:  **no work is done when an object is stationary.**

You can of course ask "what would the displacement/energy/power be if the other forces were not acting?"  But this number doesn't actually have any relation to the amount of energy/power delivered by the lift during the level flight that you're interested in.

Comment: But yet the engine is burning fuel and doing work, otherwise the aircraft would fall.

Comment: @AdrianLoteanu : Yes, and we can calculate the work done by the engines to push the plane forward along its level path, and the corresponding (negative) work done by drag due to that same motion.  But no work is done by the lift or by gravity in level flight.

Comment: But if you look at thrust vs drag there is also no displacement. Since the speed is constant in the example, thrust and drag cancel out and the object does not get any acceleration along the x-axis. How does this work?

Comment: @AdrianLoteanu:  If the plane is moving horizontally, then there is indeed displacement;  the plane moves a certain horizontal distance. The work done by the thrust is then the force of the thrust times this displacement, while the work done by the drag is *minus* the force of the drag times this displacement, since the drag vector and the displacement vector are in opposite directions but of equal magnitude. ...

Comment: ... The positive work done by the thrust and the negative work done by the drag cancel out, leaving a net work of zero, meaning no change in kinetic energy according to the work-energy theorem, meaning constant velocity. It's all consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The work done by a force depends on the actual displacement of an object, rather than that which would occur in the absence of other forces. For example gravity does no work on an object at rest supported by the Earth's surface.

The power required to maintain level flight at constant velocity $v$ is
\begin{equation}
P = -\mathbf{F}_{Aerodynamic} \cdot \mathbf{v} = F_D v
\end{equation}
where $F_D$ is drag. It's possible to express this in terms of the lift to drag ratio ($C_L / C_D$) and weight ($mg$):
\begin{equation}
P =  \frac{mgv}{\left ( \frac{C_L}{C_D} \right )} .
\end{equation}

Comment: How does one calculate the CL/CD ratio? One of the things I am interested in knowing is how much (%) of the engine power goes to providing lift and how much to countering drag in a typical aircraft.

Comment: @AdrianLoteanu - See Figure 120 in [Page 116 of this NASA document](https://practicalaero.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/NASA-SP-367.pdf#page=119) for an example of the L/D ratio as a function of angle of attack. Peak CL/CD is about 18 for this particular airfoil for example.